# Does shiny ui.R support including html pages on each tabPanel with-in tabsetPanel?

Tags: javascript, r, html, shiny, html-rendering

I am a newbie to Shiny and I was trying to includeHTML onto tabPanel within tabsetPanel and was facing issues like only one of the HTML page getting rendered, so was wondering if shiny ui.R support multi HTML inclusion in tabsetPanel and if so what would be the things that need to be taken care of?

Also, why does shiny ui.R view page source doesn't display complete page source?
Thanks!

ui.R sample as below (just the mainPanel extract) trying to render info.html/daily.html as below

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Info1", 
             div(h6("Top empl")),
             div(class = "row", div(showOutput("topten", "nvd3"), class = "span4")),
    )
    , tabPanel("Info2", 
             div(h6("Top empl")),
             div(class = "row", div(showOutput("topten", "nvd3"), class = "span4")),
    )
    , tabPanel("Info3", dataTableOutput(outputId="table"))     
    , tabPanel("Monthly Info", includeHTML("www/info.html"))
    , tabPanel("Daily Info",includeHTML("www/daily.html"))
    , tags$head(tags$script(src="collapsible.js"))
  )
```

)

Comment: Are you looking to render multiple HTML tables within one tabsetPanel, or just HTML elements?  I typically use the HTML() code to format objects with HTML on the page.

For example:  

    `p(HTML("<i>Lorem ipsum</i>"))`

Comment: I am trying to include HTML page in each tabPanel; I get it rendered for one of the tabPanel and meanwhile the other will be lost. So, trying to figure out how to include HTML page onto each tabPanel.

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: @Mark, I have included a sample extract of what I am trying to achieve, please let me know if that makes sense. Thx.

Comment: @Ravi, I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I would like to see the solutions if any.

Answer (score 3):

You can replicate the following app which has the Monthly Info Tab. Its content is a HTML file located in the same directory with the app.R.

```
ui <- function(input, output) {
mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Info1"),
                tabPanel("Info2"), 
                tabPanel("Info3"),
                tabPanel("Monthly Info",
                         includeHTML("test.html")))
        )
}

server <- function(input, output){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i've also had issues with includeHTML using a knitted html of a R Markdown file in a NavbarPage layout: the html would look fine but all the other tabs would stop working!
I eventually found a solution on this page: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/303 
Basically, instead of using

```
output: html_document
```

in your markdown yaml, you should use:

```
output: html_fragment
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using includeCSS() instead of includeHTML().

Comment: It's not a full answer. Please add some explanation